# how is self different in __init__ vs a standard instance method

Tags: python, object, constructor, initialization

consider this simple class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def afunc(self):
        pass
```

Typically self is a reference to the object, but the init function is responsible for creating the object so how can self be a reference to something that doesn't exist? What is the difference in self for these two functions?

Comment: *"is responsible for creating the object"* - no, it isn't. It's responsible for *initialising it* once created. `__new__`, which is a classmethod, creates the object.

Answer (score 0):

When `__init__` is called `self` *does* exist.
`__init__` is for initializing, and `__new__` creates it.